# Javascript if statement inside jQuery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick noobish question.
Can you put if statement inside `jQuery` append function?

I have this code

```
$('table#dataTable tbody').append('<tr>
<td class="success">'+json.forms[i].name+'</td><td>'+json.forms[i].category+'</td>
</tr>');
```

And i would like to add an if statement to the second `<td></td>` like `if(something === x){ do it)else{don't do it};` and then continue with append.

Comment: Use string concatenation with ternary operator\

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you give me an example?

Comment: `'<tr><td class="success">' + json.forms[i].name + '</td><td>' + (x == 'something' ? json.forms[i].category : '') + '</td></tr>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do the concatenation outside the append

```
var html = '<tr><td class="success">'+json.forms[i].name+'</td>'
if (something == x)
{
   html += '<td>'+json.forms[i].category+'</td>';
}
html += '</tr>';

$('#dataTable tbody').append(html);
```

Or use a ternary operator as @ArunPJohny said

```
var html = '<tr><td class="success">'+json.forms[i].name+'</td>'
html += something == x ? '<td>'+json.forms[i].category+'</td>' : '';
html += '</tr>';

$('#dataTable tbody').append(html);
```

Single line

```
var html = '<tr><td class="success">'+json.forms[i].name+'</td>' + (something == x ? '<td>'+json.forms[i].category+'</td>' : '') + '</tr>';
$('#dataTable tbody').append(html);
```

Comment: that would work as well.

Comment: Thanks boss! Worked.